# How to move/copy a file from one one location to the other using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using the Phonegap File API but am having trouble copying a file from one location to the other.

- my targeted device is iOS(ipad)
- my iOS version is 9.2.1
- I am working on windows platform
- I am using phonegap build

### my requirement :

I am capturing a video and its getting saved in some temp folder by default here is the location where its getting saved (`/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2183897E-3660-4145-A822-76F5B763E48D/tmp/capture-T0x17e7cae0.tmp.avqBi2/capturedvideo.MOV`)

So I just want to move this (`capturedvideo.MOV`) video to photo album location in my ipad

This is my code which i am trying to make it work.

```
function success(entry) {
console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
}

function fail(error) {
alert(error.code);
```

}

```
function moveDir(entry) {
var parent = document.getElementById('parent').value,
    parentName = parent.substring(parent.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
    newName = document.getElementById('newName').value,
    parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(parentName, parent);

// move the directory to a new directory and rename it
entry.moveTo(saveToPhotoAlbum, newName, success, fail);
```

}

Any help or working examples would be great.

Thanks

Nik`

Comment: Any help or working examples would be great.
Thanks
Nik

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Tell me how to <x>" questions are not a good fit for this site. Post your current code and tell your readers specifically how it's not working and somebody should step up and help you. (I would also suggest adding "Phonegap" to the subject so it catches the attention of people who know that framework. I know almost nothing about Phonegap, so I can't help you.)

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: [cross-post](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how-to-save-captured-video-audio-in-ios-photo-albums-jlqgt2gjrf4hc)

Comment: did you ever solve this in a satisfactory way? I'm trying to do exactly the same as you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible on iOS, because Apple does not allow to move videos, images or any other files out of the app sandbox to other folders. The reason that the standard-camera on the iPad/iPhone is able to place pictures there is simply because this is a built-in feature that has special permissions which your third-party app will not be able to get.
This is of course only true as long as the device is not jailbroken.

For more infos, especially concerning the file-system layout and what you are allowed to store, you should take a look at the cordova-file-plugin Readme on Github:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file